# Apache Spark partition by output path

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a CSV data like below.

```
tenantId, siteId, TrackingID
1,A,V
2,V,V
1,A,V
2,C,D
```

I need to partition this data by `tenantId` and store it into directory like `{tenantid}\sample1.csv`, i.e.

```
C:\1\sample1.csv
C:\2\sample1.csv
```

I see that Spark's `partitionBy` creates directories differently, using partition column name like
`C:\**tenantid**=1\sample1.csv`

Is there any approach that I can solve this problem?

Comment: No, output path always will have column name in it...

Comment: @AlexOtt not exactly "always"

Comment: I am pretty new to spark, just help me understand this. is it possible to write custom code and achieve this? any guidance.